# Как создать операции с TimeOut?

Tags: c#

Предположим, папка находится на каком-то сетевом ресурсе к которому низкая скорость доступа.

Если я просто попытаюсь открыть через стандартные C# методы работы с файловой системой, то программа подвинет.

Можно вынести это в отдельный Task, но в таком случае я все равно не смогу воспользоваться cancellationtoken, так как внутри Task'а, когда я вызову функцию работы с файловой системой, то я не смогу его проверять.

Корректно ли кокнеретно в этом случае абортить поток? Вроде, как везде пишут, что это плохо...

Comment: Почему это не сможете проверять? В цикле асинхронно работаете с файловыми потоками и проверяете токен. | Рекомендую к прочтению небольшую книгу (большую статью) [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957) (доступна официально бесплатна). В конце там приведен пример асинхронного копирования.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, ну вот я вызвал Directory.GetFiles на шару, которая где-то находится. Как я могу проверять какие-либо токены, если Directory.GetFiles синхронен => я жду и не могу выполнять проверки токенов.

Comment: Открытие (не копирование) одного файла (или доступ к одной папке) тоже неприемлемо долго или нормально? | Не используйте `GetFiles`, используйте `EnumerateFiles`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov даже если использовать EnumerateFiles, то есои есть какие-то проблемы с сетью или учетными данными, то винда секунд 30 стучится. А я вот этого как раз хочу избежать. Если за 5 сек я не получаю желаемого, то хочу обрубать.